# Getting value from SQL query to textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, vb.net, ado.net

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cons, query As String
    Dim con As OdbcConnection
    Dim adpt As OdbcDataAdapter
    'Dim num As Integer
    cons = "dsn=Courier; UID=Courier; PWD=123;"
    con = New OdbcConnection(cons)

    con.Open()

    query = "select Name from EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Dim ds As DataSet
    adpt = New OdbcDataAdapter(query, con)
    ds = New DataSet
    adpt.Fill(ds, "Courier")

    ' TextBox1.Text = ds

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

I want to display the name of the employee in Textbox whoos ID is specified in query, what can I do for that?

Comment: You can start reading some book about .NET programming

Answer (score 2):

You should use DataRow but to answer your question, try this.

```
TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name").ToString()
```

Comment: I think ExecuteScalar is better

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want one value back you should skip the dataset and adapter altogether.

```
query = "select Name from EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue
Dim TempName As String = query.ExecuteScalar
TextBox1.Text = TempName
```

ExecuteScalar returns the first cell of the first row, that's all you need.

You should read about [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx%20%22parameters) as well.